# Change order increment id while submitting order

Tags: magento-1.8, sales-order, payment-gateway

Is there any method to change the order increment id while submitting the order? My client wants to change the prefix of order_id if the order is paid through a particular payment gateway.

Please let me know.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this
http://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/

Thecoderin,it `too complex process to change order_id` on basic of payment is done/not.
Because of you

```
1.`want to prefix only case of order paid`, and
2.`Most important is this field is auto increment field.`
```

### As a alternative Solution:

add new field to order table sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_grid

then using magento [event/observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) you update field.

Magento event/list https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know why we cannot change the order increment id before submitting the order? Is the order id set before we submit the order?